# In VS Code, how can I open the same file in multiple tabs of the same editor group?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs

Sometimes I want to open the same file multiple tabs, each tab focusing on a different line/method, in Eclipse this is easy, but I haven't found a way to do it in VS Code? screenshot from Eclipse doing it:
[image]

Split view isn't enough, right now I'm on a 14" laptop with no extra display available, the laptop screen is too small to comfortably use split view.

Comment: "Duplicate Workspace" allows the same file opened in multiple VSCode instances at least, one tab for each instance, but that's not nearly as convenient as in Eclipse's same instance different tabs. reminds of the days when web browsers didn't have tabs (:

Comment: edit your question with this comment

Comment: each file can only be once in each tab group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Microsoft has no plans to implement the [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/41289), an alternative solution is to create a symlink of the file: `ln -s code.c code.ln.c` and have `*.ln.c` in `.git/info/exclude`  then VSCode threats them as 2 different files, even though editing 1 of them is instantly reflected in the second (-:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is a clunky [workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/41289#issuecomment-651399367) in the [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/41289):

1. In Explorer, right-click the target file, click "Select for Compare"
2. right-click the same file, click "Compare with Selected"
3. Toggle inline view for diff

Some links with visual guide to achieve this:

https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/compare-contents-of-two-files-in-vs-code
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_diffs

P.S. This workaround however can only open 2 tabs of the same file concurrently within the same tab group

Comment: @hanshenrik an alternative I personally used on my small laptop is to imitate bookmark feature in most modern IDEs which vscode lacks :(

`F9` to toggle breakpoint

Add keyboard shortcuts to move to next and previous breakpoints

`editor.debug.action.goToNextBreakpoint` - `Ctrl + Alt + .`

`editor.debug.action.goToPreviousBreakpoint` - `Ctrl + Alt + ,`

Comment: haha found a different workaround: make a symlink of the file: `ln -s file.c file2.c` , and put file2.c in .git/info/exclude :) and open both files in vscode

Comment: Haha nice, I guess you can one up that, `ln -s file.c file_2_dup.c`, then append generic filter into .gitignore with `**/*_dup.*`, that way you don't have to keep adding each of them and also just make sure they're placed somewhere safe from cmake GLOB

Comment: It's unfortunate we had to resort to workarounds like this. VS code team deemed this feature as out-of-scope, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/41289#issuecomment-723437161

Comment: the out-of-scope closure s additionally explained [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/189793#issuecomment-1668053543).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `Split Editor` feature in VS Code.

Check the following image for details.

[image]

Comment: nope, i want them in different tabs, not in split view. right now i'm programming on a 14" laptop, with no extra displays available, and the laptop screen is too small to comfortably use split screen

Comment: Just drag-and-drop the second tab onto the first to merge them into a single view.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if there is another solution, but this should work: Right click on the tab and then select Split [Up|Down|Left|Right]:

[image: Split edit window in VS Code]

Comment: nope, i want them in different tabs, not in split view. right now i'm programming on a laptop, with no extra displays available, and the laptop screen is too small to comfortably use split screen ^^ (~14" laptop)

Comment: Ah, okay, fair enough. The laptop part is missing in your question.

Comment: hmm good point, question updated ^^

Answer (score -1):

On the latest VSCODE version at this moment, v 1.84.2, there is an easy way to open two instances of a file side by side to compare different parts of the content, for example two methods that achieve the same result.

In the vscode explorer open a file as usual, just double clicking on it, then rigth click over the same file on vscode explorer and pick "Open to the Side" menu or alternativelly press Ctrl + Enter.

You will have two tabs with independent vertical scroll to compare different parts of the content.

Comment: did you **read the question and the other answer posts**? this has already been stated several times, and the asker has already had to state several times that this is not what they are looking for. And I even edited the title two months ago to help clarify.