# How to duplicate the view of a file in two tabs in Visual Studio Code without splitting?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to duplicate the view of a file into two tabs in Visual Studio Code.

I know that I can duplicate the view of a file splitting the window in two columns. So I need the same, but not splitting the window rather showing the duplicate view in another tab.

Comment: open a second tab group (if not already open) and open the same file in that tab group

Comment: @rioV8 But, how can I open a second group of tabs?

Comment: @startball Yes, but that solution it's a trick, not a feature. I used SublimeText and to do a new file view it was very simple using "File: New view into File" command.

Comment: The closest you are going to get is the `View: Split Editor in Group` command.  It opens another view to the same file IN THE SAME TAB, it doesn't open another tab.  But it reduces tab clutter because the two views into one file are combined into a single tab.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69111951/836330

Comment: @starball they want something like the diff view, the same file with 2 different scroll bars but in one tab, what is the visual advantage of not having a split, Emacs does a split, vim does a split, if he wants feature X from editor Y, use editor Y

Comment: Magenta, please speak on what rioV8 is suggesting that you want. That is not my understanding based on your question post as it currently is written.

Comment: @starball The solution provided in the link you sent me still worked for me. Now I'm using it, although it has the limitation that only one additional tab can be created. It seems that natively, VSCode doesn't have that feature. I will make a feature request on GitHub. Additionally, I'll see if this feature can be added through an extension. I'm used to having three or four tabs open with the same file in Sublime Text. It's very convenient when there are many lines of code.

Comment: well, good luck, given that the feature request has [already been raised and closed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/41289) (not sure why it was closed). please ping me with a link to the feature-request issue ticket you raise.

Comment: @starball Oh, the request was from 2018. Here is my [feature-request issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/189793)

Comment: In short words, this won't be possible for now and for a long time. They replied me this _"The core VS Code Architecture does not support this, so there are no plans in the short term to do a rewrite for this feature."_

Comment: yes, I commented this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73565512#comment135490116_73583423). Please let this question be closed as a duplicate of the post I suggested.